# Problem with Docker file that gives Apache2 error (AH00558)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache2

I have Docker installed on Windows 10 with Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).
I have the following docker-compose.yml in my /home/project folder on the Ubuntu system:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "8086:3306"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "1025:1025" # smtp server
      - "8025:8025" # web ui

volumes:
  db:
```

I then run `docker compose up`

The database and mailhog are starting up just fine but Wordpress/Apache2 gives me the following errors from the console

```
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | [Tue Aug 10 12:35:34.558581 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress_1  | [Tue Aug 10 12:35:34.558632 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

It worked just before I went on vacation and I have no clue what's going on since I haven't changed anything on my work computer.

All help appreciated :)

Comment: Those seem like normal startup messages.  Is the container actually working?

Answer (score 0):

I took your docker-compose.yml and ran it.
No problems.

Same error messages:

```
wordpress_1  | Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
wordpress_1  | No 'wp-config.php' found in /var/www/html, but 'WORDPRESS_...' variables supplied; copying 'wp-config-docker.php' (WORDPRESS_DB_HOST WORDPRESS_DB_NAME WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD WORDPRESS_DB_USER)
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress_1  | [Tue Aug 10 16:13:25.512446 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.22 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress_1  | [Tue Aug 10 16:13:25.512536 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

But when I go to localhost:8181 I see the Wordpress install-screen (select language, etc)

So, the errors seem to be ok.